# ManagementObjectSearcher - Cross Reference information from two classes (c#)

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

OK..Lets see if I can make this question make any sense :/

I have made a query that allows me to see NetworkAdapter class information for a selected NIC. I somehow want to include information from the NetworkAdapterConfiguration class in the same query (IPAddress, DefaultGateway etc). PLEEEEEEES HELP!!

```
intquery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE Description ='" + comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString()+ "'");
        ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = intquery.Get();
        queryCollection = intquery.Get();
```

This is the other query for tcp/ip info

```
ManagementObjectSearcher query = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = 'TRUE'");
        ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection1 = query.Get();
```

Can i merge them to select from the same combo box??

Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Win32_NetworkAdapterSetting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394218%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class which is an `association class` that represents the relationship between the [`Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) classes. check this [`How to join in a WMI Query (WQL)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206846/how-to-join-in-a-wmi-query-wql) to see how the Associations class works (the link show another WMI classes, but you can figure out how use it in your case)

Comment: Im just trying to figure it in c# :/

Comment: Still no joy, don't suppose you can supply a code example. Sorry Im such a noob!!!