# Converting a drive letter to a Partition ID / Disk ID

Tags: windows, winapi, drive-letter, deviceiocontrol

Given a drive letter, how do I get the [OSImage InstallTo Partition ID](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff716430.aspx) and [Disk ID](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff715610%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) without using the registry?

Comment: Hi; with that Partition ID you mean 1 based index of the partition ?

Comment: See here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff716430.aspx. This is what I need to determine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `WMI` class `Win32_DiskPartition` is what I need. Now to figure out how to use `WMI` to get this information from a drive letter.

`Win32_LogicalDisk` is also useful, [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390423.aspx), and [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3222349/504239).

**Update:** Hmm, this doesn't work! Not in the Windows Installer anyway ([WMI is missing from Windows PE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/83defbc5-1cdb-470f-b5f1-f1fe6a61fc74/)!!) so I am using the other answer `QueryDosDevice` (e.g. `\\.\PhysicalDisk1\Partition0`) and hacking it together. This sucks Microsoft, accept a damn path in your installer.

---

**Answer:** `IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS` works to get the `Disk ID`. And DeviceIoControl `IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX` (thanks TLama) gets me the `Partition ID`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried simply calling [`QueryDosDevice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365461.aspx)?

Comment: This doesn't look like it gives me the Disk ID # nor the partition ID. I am working with the program that installs Windows itself. The setup wants a disk id and a partition id. Not a virtual mapping.

Comment: @unixman83: So the returned "target path" isn't something along the lines of `"\\.\PhysicalDisk1\Partition0"`?

Comment: Hmm, the docs said differently: `\Device\HarddiskVolume1`. I didn't try it. I guess that would work. I'll have to try it tomorrow.

Comment: @unixman83: I didn't try it either.  Now I see the sentence in the documentation you're talking about.  I think both forms are valid, one must be a link to the other.  Then we just need to figure out how to follow symbolic links in the device namespace.